# Did Michael Collins ask for a fourth gimbal for Christmas? Is there a recording or transcript?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, history, apollo-11

Did Apollo 11 Command Module Pilot Michael Collins ask for a fourth gimbal for Christmas, while looking for the lunar ascent module? If so, is a recording of this available for posterity? Or a transcript?

Video cued at `02:24`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A transcript exists in the [Apollo 11 Lunar Surface Journal, Postlanding Activities](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.postland.html#1050000), with extensive annotations. The exchange begins at Mission Elapsed Time 104:59:27. Owen Garriott has just taken over as CapCom:

> **104:59:27** Garriott: Columbia, Houston. Over.
>
> **104:59:34** Collins: Columbia. Go.
>
> **104:59:35** Garriott: Columbia, Houston. We noticed you are maneuvering very close to gimbal lock. I suggest you move back away. Over.
>
> **104:59:43** Collins: Yeah. I am going around it, doing a CMC Auto maneuver to the Pad values of roll 270, pitch 101, yaw 45.
>
> **104:59:52** Garriott: Roger, Columbia. (Long Pause)
>
> **105:00:30** Collins: (Faint, joking) How about sending me a fourth gimbal for Christmas.
>
> *[Armstrong - "This is Mike at his best. We had a four-gimbal platform on Gemini."]*

followed by several paragraphs explaining in depth what gimbal lock is and why it would risk losing the inertial platform (IMU) orientation and necessitate a lengthy reinitialisation.

This discussion also links to an ALSJ background page about [Gimbal Angles, Gimbal Lock, and a Fourth Gimbal for Christmas](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/gimbals.html) where the above transcript excerpt reappears. A fourth gimbal for Apollo had been considered by MIT in 1963

> The difficulties near gimbal lock can be avoided by the addition of a fourth gimbal to the IMU. (...)

at the expense of extra mechanical and computational and operational complexity.